# Restart pod depend on health check

Tags: sql, azure, azure-aks

I am using Azure Kubernetes service, I found sometimes I'm getting failing health checks to SQL Server, then my API is responding to any request with code 400.

In this case, a simple pod restart usually helps; I thought that liveness / readyness probes will manage that in such scenario, but it's not.

Any ideas how may i automatize restarts on pods if this happened again?

Comment: Probably depends on what is the endpoint you use for the liveness probe. Also the healthz endpoint return 400?

Comment: @JacopoBernasconi im using this pod as api to collect data from external endpoint, then push it to database, healt check from database return status unhealty and data which i collect isn't goes there(what is obvious due DB is unhealthy),  in this scenario helps restart of my pod, but i would like to make it automaticly. I would like to know if there is possibility to restart this pod when healt check from database is in status unhealthy

Comment: I understand, my question is, when your db connection is lost, your healthz endpoint (the status) return an "error" code? like 500? because liveness check doesn't check the HTML, only the HTTP code.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor and restart unhealthy docker containers. This functionality was proposed to be included with the addition of HEALTHCHECK, however didn't make the cut. This container is a stand-in till there is native support for --exit-on-unhealthy https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/22719

Sample compose file is:

```
docker run -d \
    --name autoheal \
    --restart=always \
    -e AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL=all \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    willfarrell/autoheal
```

Simply execute `docker-compose up -d` on this

a) Apply the label autoheal=true to your container to have it watched.

b) Set ENV AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL=all to watch all running containers.

c) Set ENV AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL to existing label name that has the value true.

Refer official document https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/autoheal/ for more details.

Comment: The OP asking about Kubernetes, not pure docker.